# How can i define the variable w inside the javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
var w;
if (window.eventListener) w.addEventListener('load', startSlideShow, false);
    else w.addEventListener('onload', startSlideShow);
```

First there was no var w;
So when i browsed to the page and did inspect elemnt i saw in red a message say:

Uncaught ReferenceError: w is not defined on line 181

Now after i added the line var w;
I did inspect elemnt again and now i see in red:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

So i guess just doing var w; is not the right way.
So how do i define the variable w ?

Comment: What is `w`? Is is meant to be `window`? Why not just use `window`?

Comment: @Andy: because he likely copy-pasted this code from somewhere and has no idea how it works.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Store a (_the_) global variable in a new variable and then use it? What?

Comment: @Cerbrus: so that the rest of the script can now resolve this name.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Instead of just using extra variables, how about fixing the code, and removing redundant variables?

Comment: @Cerbrus: variables are cheap.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: No excuse to just create random variables everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var w = some_value_which_needs_to_be_an_object_with_an_addEventListener_method;
```

Since you are using a load event that might be an image, an iframe or maybe the main window object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `w`, use `window`:

```
if (window.eventListener)
    window.addEventListener('load', startSlideShow, false);
else
    window.addEventListener('onload', startSlideShow);
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain the nature of the error.

With `var w;` the variable `w` is only declared, or a set variable, but it is also `null` (or `undefined`, whichever javascript prefers...).

Using `.addEventListener` is treating the variable as a reference to an object, because you are attempting to call a method of the would-be object.

However because the variable has "nothing" assigned (provided value), you are attempting to call a method on a non-existent object, commonly resulting in languages like Java as a `NullPointerException`.

That is, using/accessing a property/method of something that does not exist.  Like expecting to get something from an empty box.

Comment: `var w` --> `w == undefined`. Not `null`.

Comment: @Cerbrus when in javascript have you suffered the difference between `null` and `undefined`?